# What is The best way to Handle Request timeout in mongodb in python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["game"]
mycol = mydb["test_collection"]


def foo(bar, baz):
    res = mycol.find()
    result = json.loads(dumps(res))
    return result

def handle_cache(request):
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=4)
    async_result = pool.apply_async(foo, ('world', 'foo')) 
    return_val = async_result.get()
    return JsonResponse(return_val, safe=False)
```

Here i am fetching records from mongodb using pymongo client with python.
I have 10 million plus records available in the database.

so sometimes it is giving below error:

```
    mongodb operationfailure request timeout
```

Above i have some piece of code to handle this.

Is this good way to do it?
will it never fail no matter it take 1 min also?
Or Is there any better way to do this?

PLease have a look.